# Font in GVedit Editor

Tags: editor

Is it possible to change  the font size of the code in in GVedit Editor?

I do not mean the font of text in created graphs, but the font size of the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the text from webpage or word to GVEdit, the format will not change.
But I haven't find where to config it.